# How is it possible to draw a break into chart.js v2 barchart it the data is out of bounds of the axis scales

Tags: angularjs, layout, data-visualization, chart.js

As you can see on bar **C** in the chart below the bar is displayed with an overflow. I'd like to draw something like a breakpoint when a value is too big for the axis scale. 
In my opinion this could be a fade-out effect on the bars end or a break of the bar like this `----//-`.

I also created a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBMpMx) for this example.

[image]